# Spatial Join for two variable visualization

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I want to know if I can use Spatial Join functions for visualize a dataset based in two variables.

My csv has 541000 rows and I'm trying to make a visualization in Zeppelin with Spark to minimize de point draws.

All examples I've seen are to GIS systems but there are not the type of data I need. 
My csv is this:

```
id, variableX, variableY, type.
```

I'm trying to apply a Spatial Join logic to variableX and variableY.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[**spark-highcharts**](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) might do what you want.

It's too much to plot half million points directly. There are some aggregation or filter needed. spark-highcharts will do the aggregation automatically.

> For 2 dimension data, chart type like, `line`, `area`, `spline`.
>
> For 3 dimension data, chart type like, `arearange`, `scatter` can be used.

With following code to plot bank data provided in Zeppelin Tutorial. It can plot a spline chart with xAxis use column `age`, and yAxis using aggregated average `balance`

```
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts.model._

highcharts(bank.series("name" -> "age", "y" -> avg($"balance")).orderBy($"age")).
  xAxis(new XAxis("age").typ("category")).
  chart(Chart.spline).
  plot()
```

[image]

Comment: The execution shows an error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function.

Comment: I've tryed to do the following:
highcharts(mydata.series("name" -> "variableX", "y" -> avg($"variableY")).orderBy($"variableX")).
  xAxis(new XAxis("variableX").typ("category")).
  chart(Chart.spline).
  plot()

Comment: This is not an built in package for zeppelin, so it need be included and imported. Please following the github page for instructions.

Comment: Yes, I know! The package is included in spark interpreter and the imports works fine. The problem is when I'm trying to execute the function.

Comment: I believe the error was due to not import correctly. I can not see why it does not work. Can you post in a separate question with the stacktrace?

Comment: I've posted a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931296/error-showing-data-with-spark-highcharts